# how to logout session if user idle in php

Tags: php

I am new to php and am trying to build a website. I would like to logout user session if he is idle for some time. I searched the web but i couldn't find the proper code. How do you check whether user is idle or not in php?. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Here are a couple...

- set a session expiry time, such that after a certain amount of time, the session expires and is no longer valid.
- set a 'time' flag as session data, and check if their session is still 'new enough' to keep them logged in each pageload.

I would opt for the second choice, as it can be difficult to set the right values in PHP such that the session expires securely, and the way you want it to. With the second option, all you have to do is make sure the session will *not* expire *before* you want it to, which is easier.

Code example for option 2:

```
//on pageload
session_start();

$idletime=60;//after 60 seconds the user gets logged out

if (time()-$_SESSION['timestamp']>$idletime){
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}else{
    $_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
}

//on session creation
$_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
```

---

EDIT:

Your comment explains that you'd actually like to keep track of mouse events and other things on the client side to determine if the user is idle. This is more complicated. I will give a general solution, and then offer a couple suggestions for optimizations and improvements.

To accomplish what you've described, you must **track clientside activity** (mouse movements, keyboard strokes etc) and **process that information on the server side**.

**Tracking clientside activity** will require javascript event handlers. You should create an event handler for every action you want to count as 'not being idle', and keep track (in a javascript variable) of when the last time they've been idle is.

**Processing that info on the server side** will require you to use **ajax** to send the last time they've been idle to the server. So every few seconds, you should send the server an update (using javascript) which specifies how long the user has been idle.

A couple extra suggestions:

1. You should not rely on this ajax solution as the only way to track user activity, as some users will not have JS enabled. So, you should also track user activity on pageload. Accordingly you should probably not set the idle time too low (at least for non-JS users), as non-JS users will not be sending any data to the server until pageloads occur.
2. You should send updates to the server via ajax as infrequently as possible about user activity to decrease demand on the server. To do this, simply have javascript keep track of when the user would time out. If it gets to the point where the user is about to time out (say, in about a minute or so), *then and only then* ping the server.

Comment: You could also use a timer in JavaScript that would take you to a login page after that time is up.

Comment: incrediman

Thanks for the reply.But that does not check whether user is idle or not such as we need to check mouse events and so on. It simply makes user logout after the specified time.

Comment: @sudh: To do that is more complicated, and requires javascript. I will update my answer.

Comment: +1 all round, but I can't rely on JS being enabled. It ought to be, but if it isn't then I still need a PHP only solution, so will go with that for v1.0.  "Client side activity" will be defined as submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can config the PHP - configuration for `session.cookie_lifetime`, this will automatic destroy session after amount of idle time. 
More information can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Comment: +1 thanks. I need to set it to the max, then make sure that I poll more often. I have updated the question because I forgot to point out that my PHP needs to be aware of the timeout in order to update the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `session_cache_expire`, I give you this example :

```
 <?php

/* set the cache limiter to 'private' */

session_cache_limiter('private');

$cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter();

/* set the cache expire to 30 minutes */

session_cache_expire(30);

$cache_expire = session_cache_expire();

/* start the session */

session_start();

echo "The cache limiter is now set to $cache_limiter<br />";

echo "The cached session pages expire after $cache_expire minutes";

?>
```

Source : [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php)

Comment: +1 thanks. I need to set it to the max, then make sure that I poll more often. I have updated the question because I forgot to point out that my PHP needs to be aware of the timeout in order to update the database.