# What is the code for Stay logged in or Remember me while user login in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I don't know how to write php code for **Stay logged in or remember me** while user check the option while login. I want to stay user logged in at least 60min until user close the browser. What is the code for this in PHP.

Comment: Are you using sessions? Then this should be pretty much the default behavior.

Comment: @deceze: Yes i am using sessions

Comment: Please give me some code instead of links. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using session, this would probably help

```
function lifetime(){
    $inactive = 3600; //60 minutes, i suppose in seconds
    if(isset($_SESSION['start']) ) {
        $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['start'];
        if($session_life > $inactive){
            //your log out code
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).
These threads will help you:

- [Stay logged in & remember me - PHP sessions and cookies](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/881197-stay-logged-remember-me-php-sessions-cookies)
- [how to logout session if user idle in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453831/how-to-logout-session-if-user-idle-in-php/3453844#3453844)

You can use [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set specific time of session life.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php This should be helpful

Comment: No. `Remember me` using cookies)

Answer (score 0):

You should use cookies for this:
[cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)