# I'm trying session expire when compter goes aftersleep mode

Tags: php, windows, session, sleep

I'm trying session expire when computer goes sleep mode after 1min. How i need to implement this one.

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    session_start();
    $myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
    $ses_sql=mysql_query("select nocname from nocusers where nocname='$myusername' ");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
    $login_session=$row['nocname'];
    if(!isset($login_session))
    {
    header("Location:login.php");
   }
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to logout session if user idle in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453831/how-to-logout-session-if-user-idle-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to change your session timeout for`1 min = 60`seconds like this

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60);
```

now you can check the session value each time on your page when load. if activity not happen within 1 min session will expire and you went to logout like this

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    session_start();

   if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
   {
      $myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
      $ses_sql=mysql_query("select nocname from nocusers where nocname='$myusername' LIMIT 1 ");
      if($row=mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql))
      {
          $_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['nocname'];
      }  
      else
      {
         // logout here
      }

   }
   else
   {
       // logout here
   }
?>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

you can also store a last activity time in your database respect to each user. and update it every time on top of each page. before it check that last updated time is less than 1 minute if yes it means no activity by this user greater than 1 minute. logout it.

Comment: Well. Thanks Shrma, But I need session expire Depend computer activity not for particular website. I made this one for employees.